# Can I generate a sequence of Rx Observables from chained AJAX calls?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, rxjs, reactivex

### Technical Context

I am using jQuery in a web browser to call an API that returns a set of entries from a log.

API requests take two parameters:

- `offset_timestamp`: an integer specifying the earliest possible entry I want
- `limit`: an integer specifying the number of records to return

**Example request and response**

```
Request with parameters:

- offset_timestamp = 100
- limit = 50


curl "https://example.com/log?offset_timestamp=100&limit=5"


Resulting JSON Response:

{
    next_timestamp: 222,
    end_of_log: false,
    entries: [
        {
            timestamp: 111,
            data: { ... }
        },
        {
            timestamp: 112,
            data: { ... }
        },

        ...

        {
            timestamp: 160,
            data: { ... }
        }
    ]
}
```

If I were using plain jQuery + callbacks, I think I'd have to chain the AJAX calls recursively. Something along the lines of:

```js
// NOTE: I have NOT tested this code.
//       I just wrote it for illustration purposes

function getBatch(offset, limit, callback) {
    var url = "https://example.com/logs?offset_timestamp=" + offset + "&limit=" + limit;
    var ajaxParams = {
        method: "GET",
        url: url
    };

    jQuery.ajax(ajaxParams))
        .done(function(data) {
            if (data.end_of_log) {
                return callback(data.entries);
            }
            return getBatch(data.next_timestamp, limit, function(entries) { 
                return callback(entries.concat(data.entires));
            });
        });
}

function processEntries(entries) {
    for (var i = 0; i < entries.length; i++) {
        console.log(i.data);
    }
}

getBatch(0, 50, processEntries);
```

Naturally, I would rather have a sequence of Observables (each holding one batch of entries) so I could use `flatMap()` to get a sequence of all entries.

### Question

If create an Observable from a jQuery call, e.g. `Rx.Observable.fromPromise(jQuery.ajax({...}))`, is it possible to use RxJS to chain together an arbitrary number of these Observables, using the value of `response.next_timestamp` from the previous call in the parameters of the subsequent call?

Answer (score 1):

I would try to use the [`expand`](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/expand.md) operator. You can also see an example of use here : [RxJs: How to loop based on state of the observable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34246398/rxjs-how-to-loop-based-on-state-of-the-observable/34246885#34246885), and here : [RxJS, how to poll an API to continuously check for updated records using a dynamic timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34545217/rxjs-how-to-poll-an-api-to-continuously-check-for-updated-records-using-a-dynam/34553635#34553635)

In short it allows you to do a recursion with observables, signalling the end of recursion by returning `Rx.Observable.empty()`.

Answer (score 1):

`Rx.Subject` allows us to write to (push data) as well as read from (subscribe) a stream. `Rx.Subject` behaves just like `Rx.Observable`, however, instances have an `onNext` method that allows us to push data.

We can model our requests as an `Rx.Subject`, and have our stream of responses depend on it. We can then subscribe to the responses and push the next request to the request stream:

```
// Represents our stream of requests
const request$ = new Rx.Subject();

// Represents our AJAX responses
const response$ = request$
    .startWith(initialRequest)
    .flatMap(makeAjaxCall)

    // Convert to a hot stream so we don't end up making an AJAX
    // request for every subscriber of this stream.
    .share();

// And we can map over response$ to get the updated timestamp
const timestamp$ = response$.map(getTimeStamp);

// And we can subscribe to the timestamp$ stream to push new requests
timestamp$.subscribe(timestamp => {
    const request = makeRequestFromTimestamp(timestamp);

    // Call onNext to push a new item onto our request$ stream
    request$.onNext(request);
});

// And we can subscribe to our responses. Note that our response$
// stream will continue indefinitely.
response$.subscribe(x => console.log(x));
```